# Calendar program with the following display option

Tags: windows, software-rec, calendar

I am looking for a calendar/diary program which can display the next N days, where N>7. Today must always be at the top of the list. The N days must always be shown even if they extend over a month or even year boundary. It seems such a natural way to plan ahead, but no calendar program I have ever seen seems to have this feature.

I am interested in either local or online applications.

**Edit:** I want the upcoming days to be displayed in a simple list, with each day shown one above another - no wrapping.

Comment: Re: off topic: I am not asking "what's a good calendar program", I am asking very specifically "does any calendar program have this very specific feature"... and none of the three suggestions so far fully satisfies my request.

Answer (score 2):

you could use google calender...

It has an "Agenda" tab that shows like 10 days, and there is a "Custom View" that you can set from 1 day to 1 month.

Comment: Not bad... but it only shows the dates where you have appointments. This means there is not much visual feedback about how far away/apart all the events are. What I'd really like to see as a series of strips, one for each day, perhaps with weekends marked in a different colour. That way you can instantly get a grasp of what's coming up and when.

Comment: The agenda one truncates blank days, the "custom" one shows all days even if they are blank. It shows them in little "day" boxes opposed to the agenda/list view though.

Comment: See edit to original post.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Outlook will display Today+N Days (up to 10 total). Weekend days are conveniently shaded in a differently color.  Days without appointments are still included.

While viewing your calendar in Outlook press **ALT+1** (through **ALT+0** for 10 days) to specify the number of days to view.  You can quickly return to a work week or full week view by pressing **CTRL+ALT+2** or **CTRL+ALT+3** respectively.

Note that Outlook arranges the days in a horizontal view, not vertically as you requested.  However I find this better when trying to get a sense of how appointments relate to each other, and if you have a widescreen monitor the horizontal layout makes sense.

Outlook 2010/2013 support this and I wouldn't be surprised if 2007 does as well.

Answer (score 0):

I like Calendar Creator from Broderbund.   You can display the calendar in multiple week format and the current appears at the top, but then you can scroll back or ahead.  It does not break between months.  It's great for a view of your appointments for the next few weeks.